# Multiple repositories under the same transaction

Tags: architecture, repository, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Imagine a situation when the application layer opens a new transaction and you want to perform 2 repository operations under this transaction. Let's say I want to add a new User with IUserRepository and afterwards save all events that were generated during User domain model state change. I open a new transaction in ApplicationLayer (TransactionScope), then perform these 2 operations. But what if tommorow I want to change the repository implementation to FileBasedRepository or HttpCloudRepository. Repositories don't know about the fact that they are running under some transaction, or should they?
The main question is about abstractions. We all strive to write code based on abstractions. What I see is if I implemented a unit of work and I update 2 aggregates using 2 repositories in application layer(repositories work with MSSql), tommorow I can't change one of the repositories implementations to httpbased or in memory based. The question is about how to write such code. Seems like I have to create an abstraction over transaction and implement rollbacks by my own for HttpUnitOfWork. Feels like my initial unit of work is tightly coupled to db and shoould be renamed DbUnitOfWork. But that's wrong again, cause there are no sql databased which don't support transactions at all.

Comment: Do you think they should know?

Comment: No, I think they shouldn't.

Comment: Is this question specific to CQRS or is it in the general DDD context?

Comment: no, its general to DDD, NLayered architecture. But it applies to CQRS as well.

Comment: in my opinion CQRS is a special case. In your example, those two operations are in fact only one and this should be made explicit. The `save` operation have such a signature that it is clear that the Aggregates state is very coupled with the generated events. In other words, a CQRS repository is not a clasic DDD repository. CQRS is perfect for DDD but it's a very different style than the clasic one. Events are first class citizens and this should be explicitly declared all over the code base or framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Repositories don't know about the fact that they are running under some transaction, or should they?

Here's what Evan's wrote, in the [Blue Book](http://a.co/jknnUpq)

> The REPOSITORY concept is adaptable to many situations.  The possibilities of implementation are so diverse that I can only list some concerns to keep in mind....
>   *Leave transaction control to the client*.  Although the REPOSITORY will insert and delete from the database, it will ordinarily not commit anything....  Transaction management will be simpler if the REPOSITORY keeps its hands off.

To be absolutely honest, I find this notion difficult to reconcile with other writings from the same chapter.

> For each type of object that needs global access, create ( a REPOSITORY ) that can provide the illusion of an in-memory collection of all objects of that set.

In the languages that I normally use, in-memory collections typically manage their own state.  Doesn't that imply that transaction control should be behind the collection interface, rather than left to the client?

An additional point is that our persistence solutions have gotten a lot more complex; for Evans, the domain model was only managing writes to a single database, which supported transactions that could span multiple aggregates (ie, an RDBMS).  But if you change that assumption, then a lot of things start to become more complicated.

[cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs) offers some hints, here.  *Reading* from repositories is beautiful; you take all of the complexity of the implementation and hide it behind some persistence agnostic facade.  Writing can be trickier -- if your domain model needs support for saving multiple aggregates together (same transaction), then your "repository" interface should make that explicit.

These days, you are likely to see more support for the idea that modifications of aggregates should always happen in separate transactions.  That takes some of the pressure off of repository coordination.

Answer (score 3):

The repository has no knowledge of the context in which it is used.  As such, the repository should not be responsible for starting, committing or rollbacking a transaction.

Therefore, I always pass a UnitOfWork / DbSession / whatever to my repository.  The repository uses that UnitOfWork, and the transaction is committed outside the repository.

In pseudo code, this looks like this:

```
var uow = DatabaseContext.CreateUnitOfWork();

uow.StartTransaction();

var productRepository = new ProductRepository(uow);
var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(uow);

// ... do some operations on the repositories.

uow.Commit();
```

Comment: Okay, but whats inside unit of work object? I assume there is an opened IDbTransaction object. That means that this uof is only for supported databases by .NET. If I implement Product Repository as HttpRepository, what would be the implementation to rollback, when CustomerRepository fails?Should I implement some kind of rollback by my own?

Comment: You can offcourse only implement functionality that is supported by the technology behind it.   If you want to make a httprepository (which makes no sense to me), you cannot implement rollback since http does not support that.

Answer (score 1):

**Repositories and transaction**

To me, a Repository shouldn't know about the ambient transaction - there should be a Unit of Work-like container that keeps track of updated entities and commits the transaction when you declare the Unit of Work Complete.

**Repositories with alternative sources**

It shouldn't be a problem to mix data coming from repositories with different origins in the same unit of work. *Ideally*, the UoW would know which persistence mechanism goes with which type of entity and sort it all out in the end.

For practical reasons though, you might want to limit your UoW to a single persistent store (usually a database via an ORM) and add to repositories that have different, transaction-illiterate data sources methods like `Update(entity)` that save directly to the source when called.